# Phonegap textbox issue

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have a form in phonegap for filling the feedback.
I want user to type in text inputs as shown below ; should have the `(input type="text")` and transparent textbox should be in the image.
is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution

css

```
body
{
background-image:'path-to-image';
}
input
{
background:transparent
}
```

HTML

```
....
<body>
<input type='text' placeholder='my text'/>
</body>
.....
```

Hope it helped you.